# How do I assign the tab bar item to a specific view controller when clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
import UIKit
import ARNTransitionAnimator
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

final class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate{

@IBOutlet fileprivate(set) weak var containerView : UIView!
@IBOutlet fileprivate(set) weak var tabBar : UITabBar!
@IBOutlet fileprivate(set) weak var miniPlayerView : LineView!
@IBOutlet fileprivate(set) weak var miniPlayerButton : UIButton!    
@IBOutlet  weak var miniPlay: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var tabone: UITabBarItem!

private var animator : ARNTransitionAnimator?
fileprivate var modalVC : ModalViewController!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black

    let musicVC = MusicViewController()


    }
}
```

I am trying to assign the a tab bar item to a view controller. The current view controller is a not a special tab bard controller.( I know it would of been easier to make a tab bar controller in storyboard). The tab bar is an object made in storyboard and is connected by IBoutlet with its first bar item connected as well. Is there a way to assign the connected programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an extension on `UIViewController` which copied the tab bar item properties to it's `UITabBarItem` instance.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func copyTabBarItem(_ item: UITabBarItem) {
        tabBarItem.badgeColor = item.badgeColor
        tabBarItem.badgeValue = item.badgeValue
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            tabBarItem.isSpringLoaded = item.isSpringLoaded
        }
        tabBarItem.selectedImage = item.selectedImage
        for state in [UIControlState.application, UIControlState.disabled, UIControlState.focused, UIControlState.highlighted, UIControlState.normal, UIControlState.reserved, UIControlState.selected] {
            tabBarItem.setBadgeTextAttributes(item.badgeTextAttributes(for: state), for: state)
        }
        tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = item.titlePositionAdjustment
    }
}
```

Comment: I created an extension file but I'm having trouble with the .isSpringLoaded, Is there anything different I would need to do?